# Default public access in scala

Tags: java, scala

I read that there is no package-private (default in Java) in scala and use public access by default.

What are the rationale for this choice? Is it a good practice as the default public access make everything visible, hence part of the API?

This means extra typing to encapsulate the fields and methods (whether it be private, scoped private, protected, access).

Answer (score 28):

In Java it’s far easier to choose ‘package-private’ as the default because it is one out of only three possibilities there.

In Scala you can choose between public access (`public`), package-private access with inheritance (`protected[C]`), package-private access without inheritance (`private[C]`), class-private access (`private`), object-private access (`private[this]`), inheritance access (`protected`), `protected[this]` access (whatever you may call it) and, additionally, you have some kind of file-private access modifier (`sealed`).

It’s hard to select a default from that other than `public`.

(Considering inner methods, one could also add *method-private* to the list…)

Comment: You raised a valid point, still I would say, though scala give more and better (consistency in protected scope) choice, the default should be something which hides the implementation. In that sense, package-private access without inheritance (private[C]) in your statement. I don't mind typing extra and agree it is easy with IDE, still wondering better rationale of the choice.

Comment: But then how often would you need `private[C]`? And also, since you can nest packages, which package or class would `C` be? The outermost would be useless, the innermost would be the class where the member is defined, so it’d be simply `private`. Still a valid option of course; it’s especially the package thing which gets tricky.

Comment: But well, it’s hard to argue anyway because it’s just the way it it and it’s not as bad as it might seem.

Comment: thanks.. i will wait for some more response, as all the feature in scala is well thought, this too could be the same.. I am still learning..

Answer (score 6):

Scala has far more flexibility in choosing the visibility of something than Java, though some of Java visibility rules, related to nested classes are not translatable into Scala.

And, yes, there is package-private in Scala. It is written as `private[package]` in Scala.

The reason why Scala makes `public` the default is because it is the most common visibility used. The "extra typing" is actually *less* typing, because it is far more uncommon to make members private or protected.

One exception to that rule in Java is fields, which should be made private so one may be able to change details of implementation without breaking clients. One practical consequence of this are classes with fields and then getters and setters for each field.

In Scala, because one may be able to replace a `val` or a `var` with corresponding `def`, this is not needed.

Comment: `it is far more uncommon to make members private or protected` it may be true for attributes with getters and/or setters, but I disagree in the general case. There are much more private implementation details than public API, because the API exposes higher level methods

Answer (score 2):

This is something that gives a lot of people some trouble. I'd suggest giving [this](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-2) entry (actually the entire series) a read.

Immutability also prevents any of the funnies that generally occur with such access. It might be true that "there is more typing", but looking at IDEs, they are responsible for a lot of fud as any generated method by the IDE is usually public, which is not always valid either.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Programming Scala](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch05.html#VisibilityRules), it seems like the default public is mainly due to the [uniform access principle](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch06.html#UniformAccessPrinciple), where operator overloading allow one to define the getter as `field = newvalue`

Comment: well.. actually I read here (http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/learning-scala-uniform-access-principle) that the compiler insert a getter for uniform access. But stil the accessor is public

Comment: For uniform access principle it should suffice that default access levels for fields and methods are equal, they don't need to both be `public`.